# Wireless Power Transfer Modelling

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radio-frequency

I am trying to develop an analytical model for RF wireless power transfer from an external antenna to an implant antenna, embedded inside layers of lossy tissue. [image]

The external antenna will be positioned at some point in free-space. The dimensions/geometry of both antennas are known. I would appreciate if you could share ideas/ helpful resources on the required mathematical theory to model this.

Appreciate any help.